# move side block to centre in magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, block, move

Hi please check this link http://majorcomfort.com/index.php/benches.html[image]
in this there is a

> shop by category bock in the side bar

, i need to show this in the centre of page can anybody help me how can i do this

i have tried to

```
 <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="filter" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

> in catalog.xml
>
> and in list.html

i have use      `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('filter');?>`
  but it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I'm not clear on which block you would like it be placed in. There are a number of ways to achieve this but to give you some basic guidance.

Try turning on template hints in the backend. You will then see markup surrounding all of your various blocks. On top of the markup, you will see a file path from inside the app/ folder of your Magento install. Open up the file that corresponds to your sidebar nav (usually something like catalog/navigation/left.phtml). From there you will be able to find the specific code you need and you can place it into one of the blocks up top (e.g. category-header.phtml, header.phtml, etc..). I would however recommend creating your own block and possibly switching to a 1 column layout but again, I'm not clear on what you ultimately want your design to look like.

Let me know how else I can help.

Comment: From there you can remove the CSS styling that is applied to that layout and create your own.